# Unknown column in 'field list' even though clearly exists

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So i've found plenty of other questions regarding my problem, yet i wasn't able to apply them to my problem.

HTML form:

```
<form action="Bestellingen.php" method="post">
Voornaam: <input type="text" name="voornaam"></br>
Achternaam: <input type="text" name="achternaam"></br>
Size: <select name="sizes">
        <option value="XS">Extra small</option>
        <option value="S">Small</option>
        <option value="M">Medium</option>
        <option value="L">Large</option>
        <option value="XL">Extra large</option>
        </select></br>
<font color = red>Truncate table: </font><input type="checkbox" name="truncate"></br>
<font color = red>Drop database: </font><input type="checkbox" name="drop"></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Query:

```
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE Bestellingen(
            Voornaam varchar (20),
            Achternaam varchar (20),
            Size SET('XS','S','M','L','XL')
            )";
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Bestellingen (Voornaam, Achternaam, Size) VALUES ('$_POST[voornaam]','$_POST[achternaam]','$_POST[sizes]')";
```

Problem:
(Unknown column 'Size' in 'field list')
Even though i gave the query the
CREATE TABLE Bestellingen(Size SET('XS','S','M','L','XL'))

From other answers i gathered that maybe i'm using the wrong data type or passing the wrong data type to the query, but  i just can't find the solution.

Any help would be very appreciated

Full code (although obviously not finished):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Bestellingen.php" method="post">
Voornaam: <input type="text" name="voornaam"></br>
Achternaam: <input type="text" name="achternaam"></br>
Size: <select name="sizes">
        <option value="XS">Extra small</option>
        <option value="S">Small</option>
        <option value="M">Medium</option>
        <option value="L">Large</option>
        <option value="XL">Extra large</option>
        </select></br>
<font color = red>Truncate table: </font><input type="checkbox" name="truncate"></br>
<font color = red>Drop database: </font><input type="checkbox" name="drop"></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Joeri","password");
mysqli_select_db($con,"databank");

function frontend($connection){
    $con = $connection;
    $entry = "SELECT * FROM Bestellingen";
    $entries = mysqli_query($con,$entry);
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Voornaam</th>
    <th>Achternaam</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Betaald</th>
    </tr>";
    $count = 1;
    while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($entries)){
        echo"<form action=Bestellingen.php method=post>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$count."</td>";
        $count++;
        echo "<td>".$record['Voornaam']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$record['Achternaam']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$record['Size']."</td>";
        echo "<td>"./*$record['Betaald'].*/"</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!$con){
        die ("<font color=red>Can't connect: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."</font><br/>");
    }
    else{
        echo "<font color=green>Connection link succesful...</font></br>";
        if (mysqli_query($con,"CREATE DATABASE databank")){
            echo "<font color=green>Your database was created...</font></br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<font color=green>Database found...   </font><font color=black>(" . mysqli_error($con) . ")</font></br>";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['drop'])){
                mysqli_query($con,"DROP DATABASE databank");
                echo "<font color=blue>Dropped database...</font></br>";
            }
            else{
            mysqli_select_db($con, "databank");
            $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE Bestellingen(
            Voornaam varchar (20),
            Achternaam varchar (20),
            Size SET('XS','S','M','L','XL'),
            Betaald set('ja','nee')
            )";
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Bestellingen (Voornaam, Achternaam, Size) VALUES ('$_POST[voornaam]','$_POST[achternaam]','$_POST[sizes]')";

            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1)){
                echo "<font color=green>Table made succesfully...</font></br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<font color=green>Table found... </font><font color=black> (" . mysqli_error($con) . ")</font></br>";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['truncate'])){
                mysqli_query($con,"TRUNCATE TABLE Bestellingen");
                echo "<font color=blue>Truncated table...</font></br>";
            }
            else{
                if (mysqli_query($con, $sql2)){
                    echo "<font color=green>Registered values to table succesfully...</font></br>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<font color=red>Could not register values... </font><font color=black> (" . mysqli_error($con) . ")</font></br>";
                }
            }
            frontend($con);

            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you showed us should not be generating this error AFAIK.  But in any case, you should consider using prepared statements, which would help to avoid errors like this.

Comment: I've looked into prepared statements, i'll take it into consideration.
Also i'll dump my entire code here just incase something else might be the matter.

Comment: Seems to me that you didn't execute the first query being the table's creation. There isn't enough code here to see what does get executed.

Comment: NO!  You already quite enough code here.  Do this: Dump the raw query string to the console and then see if you can run that code directly on MySQL.

Comment: `echo"<form action=Bestellingen.php method=post>";` I don't see a closing `</form>` for it. And `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: The closing </form> is right under my submit button.

Comment: Also, i'm quite certain the table did get made as i have a front end view of my database, which does show that he made the column.

Answer (score 0):

Question closed;
I figured i already added the first few columns in a previous made draft and were already in the Database.
When i tried to re-make the table it already existed and didn't add the "Size" column.
Fix:
I deleted my table so it could be created again;
Problem solved

Sorry for the inconvenience.